# Escalate DBProvider Flutter

Tags: sqlite, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am new to working with databases in flutter. I have a data folder with a database.dart in the following form. This is fine for one table and with a few CRUD functions such as newNote or getNotes, but what happens when you have multiple tables and multiple CRUD Functions? Are you supposed to dump them all on this database.dart file making it chaotic? What are better alternatives for organization?

```
class DBProvider {
    DBProvider._();

    static final DBProvider db = DBProvider._();
    Database _database;

    Future<Database> get database async {
        if (_database != null) {
            return _database;
        }

        _database = await initDB();
        return _database;
    }

    initDB() async {
        Directory documentsDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
        String path = join(documentsDir.path, 'app.db');

        return await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onOpen: (db) async {
        }, onCreate: (Database db, int version) async {
            // Create the note table
            await db.execute('''
                CREATE TABLE note(
                    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                    contents TEXT DEFAULT ''
                )
            ''');
        });
    }

newNote(Note note) async {
    final db = await database;
    var res = await db.insert('note', note.toJson());

    return res;
}
}
```

Comment: You could have a different file for each table called `notes.dart`, `bookmarks.dart` etc.

Comment: @10101010 and would I have to load and initialize the database in every file?

Comment: I think you can initialize it just once and use it in all other files.

Comment: @10101010 do you know how?

Comment: Put the initialization code in one file. Import that file wherever you need it.